# python decorating an object with @

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns, decorator, wrapper

I want to achieve the decorator design pattern in python using the @ syntax, my code:

```
class Sandwich():
    height = 5
    width = 8

    def ingredients(self):
        print("I have bread")
    
class Cheese_decorator():
    def __init__(self,obj):
        self.obj = obj
        #something else here so the object becomes the same as the passed one except for the methods to decorate below

    #decorated method
    def ingredients(self):
        self.obj.ingredients()
        print("I also have cheese")
     
    #any other method to decorate here

sandwich = Sandwich() # this sandwich wont be decorated
cheese_sandwich = Cheese_decorator(Sandwich()) # this sandwich is decorated

sandwich.ingredients() # prints I have bread
cheese_sandwich.ingredients() # prints I have bread I also have cheese
```

is there anything I can do like:

```
sandwich = Sandwich()
cheese_sandwich = @Cheese_decorator
                  sandwich
```

?
I want to have the decorated object as a var

Comment: No. Why do you want that?

Comment: Decorators are made from functions, not classes.

Comment: @TheTridentGuy decorators can be classes.

Comment: it *seems* like you just want `cheese_sandwich = Cheese_decorator(cheese_sandwhich)`

Comment: "Decorators are made from functions, not classes. " - they can actually be made from classes - that is no the point. 

But the idea is that you apply decorator either on a function or on a class, and get a callable as the result - the @ syntax is not fit for creating the instances themselves.

Comment: Decorators just have to be *callable*; what type it actually is doesn't matter. Decorator syntax is a way to apply that callable to something (a `class` or `def` statement) that is not an expression, and thus cannot be passed directly to a function call. `Sandwich()` *is* an expression, so there's no reason not to simply write `cheese_sandwich = Cheese_decorator(Sandwich())`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of whatever theoretical text you got to read "decorator pattern" - that is not what decorators are in Python.

The `@` syntax is meant to transform either a function or a class - and usually, the result is callable itself. If a class is decorated, the result is the class modified (or a new class), that will create instances, not instances themselves, like in your example.

Moreover, as it is applicable either on a `def` or on a `class` block, the resulting name for the decorated object is the name given in the statement. (Either the name after `def` or after the `class` keyword). It also implies the `@` syntax composes with one statement, and therefore is not an "expression" - and therefore invalid on the right side of an assignment, or other arbitrary places: the `@decorator` syntax requires it to be in a line by itself.

That said, your code example, using the the `cheese_sandwich = Cheese_decorator(Sandwich())` as it is, conforms with the "decorator pattern" from text books, and you may call it so. It just won't work with the "decorator syntax" from Python.

Comment: thank you, you helped me understand that the Python decorator syntax is not made for the decorator pattern in the design patterns textbook